# Xcode Objective C - Change UILabel Text From Another Class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uilabel, iboutlet

I have 2 viewcontrollers, vc1 and vc2.

vc1 has a UILabel. vc2 has a UIButton. When the button is clicked on vc2, I want the text on vc1's uiLabel to change. How do I do that?

**vc1.h**

```
@interface vc1 : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;

@end
```

**vc1.m**

```
@interface vc1 ()

@end

@implementation vc1

@synthesize textLabel = _textLabel; 

@end
```

**vc2.m**

```
#import "vc2.h"
#import "vc1.h"

@interface vc2 ()

@end

@implementation vc2

- (IBAction)onClick:(id)sender {

    vc1 *vc1Object = [[vc1 alloc] init];  //create object

    vc1Object.textLabel.text=@"New Text";  //set new text 
}
```

My above code doesn't work because it's creating a new instance instead of accessing the original property. However, I do not know how to create getters/setters for IBOutlets, or if there is another way. How do I change the text on the UIlabel from the second viewcontroller?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use either of this:- 1. `NSNotificationCenter` 2.`KVO` 3. `Delegates` 4. `Block`

Comment: how you are managing v1 and v2? are you going from v2 to v1 ? or this v1 and v2 are uiviewcontainers? or you send back from v2 to v1 - the method will be different

Comment: @pkc456 I ended up using NSNotificationCenter, thanks for your help!

Comment: @hmzfier shall I put it as answer so that it can reach to needy persons as well ?

Answer (score 0):

> vc2.m file

- First Declare VC2 Class object after **#import "VC2.h"** as below:

  ```
  VC2 *sharedInstance;
  ```
- Declare following method and variable in vc2.h file.

  ```
  @property NSString *msg;
  +(VC2 *)sharedLogger;
  ```
- then after add follwing line of code into vc2.m file

  ```
  +(instancetype)sharedLogger
  {
       static VC2 *vc2 = nil;
       static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;

       dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
           vc2 = [[self alloc] init];
       });
  }

  - (IBAction)onClick:(id)sender {
         [VC2 sharedLogger].msg = @"New Text";
  }
  ```

> vc1.m File

- First import Header file

  ```
   #import "VC2.h"
  ```

> Write code in viewDidLoad()

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       _textLabel.text = [VC2 sharedLogger].msg;
}
```